# Is it possible to retrieve data from a phone that is no longer in existence?

Tags: data-recovery

My phone (LG) was run over by a truck and completely destroyed.  I have since purchased a new phone (LG Stylo-2) and was hoping to get data from old phone.  The old phone has been disposed of.

Comment: As the mobile device is gone, so is the data that was on that device physically. Whatever data that you allowed to sync with cloud services present in your device is still available when you login to the perticular service /app. Like your contacts in your google account.

Comment: Add your google account on new device which was on the old one, you will be able to restore contacts, google photos and perhaps data for some of the apps.

Comment: Is this question serious?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless it was backed up. Most android phones back up to google drive. If you had kept it, you might have been able to take it to a repair shop and get the data off of it.

Answer (score 0):

Since data are primarily stored physically on the device, you won't be able to retrieve all of them.

Most modern phones have a feature called "Cloud Sync", which syncs **some** of your data, primarily your contacts, caleadars, notes and settings. You can easily acquire these data by signing in to the cloud sync service with the same account.

For other data, I'm sad to tell you that it's lost. That may include your music, photo or ringtones, depending on your backups (Google Photo is good!).